# Determine the current i through the 4 ohm resistor

Tags: current, ac, voltage-divider, phasor

[image]

Due to different frequencies, i applied superposition by shorting the right source
and applied voltage division rule to get the voltage across the resistance.

Vr=3 ∠0° * 4/ (4 + 6j) = 1.666∠-56°, and Ir=Vr/R

But the answer is not correct (for the right source also). What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you short the right source you end up with this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fe0hlo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So in order to obtain the voltage across the resistor you have to take into account the second inductor.

$$
Vr=3∠0°*\frac{R1||L2}{L1 + R1||L2}
$$
R1||L2 means the parallel of Resistor 1 and Inductor 2
$$
R1||L2 = \frac{R1· j \omega L2}{R+ j \omega L2}
$$

Also you have to apply superposition shorting the left source and then adding the two results.

Comment: I calculated the answer by following this method, and found it to be

Comment: I calculated the answer by following this method, and found it to be i(t)= 0.41cos(2t-18.71) + 0.65(cos 5t -22.8). Is the answer of book wrong?

Comment: I found the right answer. There was a problem with the calculation.

Comment: Always a plesure to help ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't include the effect of the 1 H inductor, which remains in parallel with the resistor when you short the right-hand source.